# How to evaluate $\lim_{n \to 0} n\cot(n)$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I already know that the value of the limit
$$\lim_{n \to 0} n\cot(n)$$
is equal to $1$, but I'm not quite sure how to evaluate it in an airtight way. I tried L'Hopital, but it just becomes circular.

Does anybody have any hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow 0 } n \frac{\cos n }{\sin n}$$

Use $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin n}{n} = 1$.